# Thread delays in waking from AutoResetEvent.WaitOne(timeout) call

Tags: .net, multithreading, autoresetevent

I need to make a call to 3rd party library but I cannot always wait for the result.  I decided to make the call on a background thread and then wait a limited amount of time for the call to complete (best to wait, but I cannot wait forever).  My method is below.  I pass in a delegate that invokes the 3rd party method

```
        public static bool ExecuteWithTimeout(int timeout, Action a)
        {
            AutoResetEvent taskComplete = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            Logger.instance.LogTrace("thread pool request start");
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x) =>
            {
                Logger.instance.LogTrace("thread pool request invoking delegate");
                a();
                Logger.instance.LogTrace("thread pool request invoking set");
                taskComplete.Set();
                Logger.instance.LogTrace("thread pool request set complete");
            });
            return taskComplete.WaitOne(timeout);
        }
```

The problem is that the invoking thread does not seem to wake from the WaitOne() call very quickly.  If I pass in a timeout of 3000 I would expect the Waitone() call to block for no more than 3 seconds. However there seems to be a long delay between the call to .Set() and when the WaitOne() method returns.

```
20140228-13:55:03:834 Trace <thread:1> thread pool request start
20140228-13:55:03:839 Trace <thread:3> thread pool request invoking delegate
20140228-13:55:04:848 Trace <thread:3> thread pool request invoking set
20140228-13:55:04:853 Trace <thread:3> thread pool request set complete
20140228-13:55:27:443 Trace <thread:1> ExecuteWithTimeout returns
```

I check the return status from the WaitOne() and it returns true indicating that the signal was received (did not timeout)

I realize that you cannot control when a thread is scheduled to run but this takes place while the app is shutting down and not much else is going on.  Also,  waiting for 23 seconds for a thread to be scheduled to run seems excessive.

running on i5 quad core 3GHz 64 bit, .Net 4.0, Windows 7 Ultimate

What am I missing?

Comment: If it takes 5 milliseconds to call AutoResetEvent.Set() then you have indeed a problem to worry about, that shouldn't take more than a fraction of a microsecond.  You'll need to investigate deeper, there are no breadcrumbs here.  Focus first on the "not much else is going on" assumption, use a concurrency analyzer.

Comment: Where is the message "ExecuteWithTimeout returns" emitted? Maybe something executes inbetween. I do not believe that it realistically is possible to cause enough load to make a <1ms operation take 23s. This is most likely not an OS problem.; Make sure to dispose of the event. This has nothing to do with the question, though.

Comment: It could be that there are higher-priority threads running around, so those are scheduled before the waiting thread.